# WordPress category, category post and single post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to make a page of restaurant by major cities.

My first page show cities, upon clicking any city I'll show all the restaurants and cliking single restaurant i'll show its details. what is the structure of my pages.

```
home (home page)
--restaurant (layout/template-restaurant.php)
----Eastern Cape (taxonomy-province.php)
------KFC (single-restaurant.php)
```

Am I doing it right?

i am using
template-sanha-restau.php as page template.
taxonomy-province.php show provinces which got restaurants.
now i am confuse what hierarchy should i follow to show all restaurants of single province?

```
add_action( 'init', 'restau' );
function restau(){
  register_post_type( 'sanha-restau',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Restaurants' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Restaurant' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-media-text',
      'hierarchical'      => true,
      'show_ui'           => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
      'query_var'         => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'restaurants',),
      'supports'=> array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail',),
    )
  );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_restau_taxonomy' );

function create_restau_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'province',
        'sanha-restau',
        array(
            'label' => 'Province',
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

kindly advice

code for template-restaurant.php

```
/*
Template Name: Restaurants Template
The template for displaying show image in header.
*/
get_header();
$custom_terms = get_terms('province');
foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'sanha-restau',
        'orderby' => 'title menu_order',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'province',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );
     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
         echo '<div">';
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $custom_term, $custom_term->taxonomy ) ) . '">'. $custom_term->name . '</a><br>';
         echo '</div>';
     }
}
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are in the right direction. You can display all the provinces with [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) and display all the restraunts in that perticular province using [loop-restraunt.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Loop_Templates) template.

One more suggestion, you might also want to add "custom-fields" in the "supports" array of register_post_type. This will enable custom fields and will be helpful in many ways.

Comment: But its not showing expected result

Comment: i have change the permalink to 'Plain' and it start working. my whole website is based on 'Post name'

Comment: cool. Glad i could help!